# Simulating Random Matlab Process in Python Issue

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, random, rows

I'm trying to simulate a Bernoulli Resolution Process in Python. I have a Matlab example of it. Regardless of the jargon, I produce a column vector of 0's and 1's depending on some random variables.

```
num_trials = 1
b_energy_res = zeros(num_photon,num_trials);
for idx = 1:num_trials
    energy_trial = randn(1,1)*energy_sigma+3*energy_sigma;
    b_energy_res(:,idx) = rand(num_photons,1)>energy_trial;
end;

t = t+(1-b_energy_res)*1e9;
t = t/1e-12;
```

It will output some vector with 0's and 1's.

I try to do the same with Python, but I get errors. Also, I'm trying to have it so that the array in numpy has about the same frequency of values of 1 and 0. I could do a histogram to check them both. I get attribute errors:

```
b_energy_res = np.zeros(num_photon)    
energy_trial = np.random.standard_normal() * energy_sigma + 3 * energy_sigma
r = np.random.uniform(0.0,1.0,num_photon)

for i in xrange(int(num_photon)):
    if r[i] > energy_trial[i]:
        b_energy_res[i] = 1

t = t + (1-b_energy_res)*1e9
t = t*1e12
```

The error is:
    'float' has no attribute *getitem*

Also, is this producing what I want it to be?

Comment: In the future, please show the complete traceback, not just part of the error string. Posting a complete [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) instead of just a non-runnable fragment of code helps a lot as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`energy_trial` is just a single value, so you can't index into it with `energy_trial[i]`. It looks like that line should just be:

```
if r[i] > energy_trial:
```

As for whether this produces the right output, all I can say as someone with a bit of experience in Python and Matlab is that it *looks* right. You may be able to get further help if you ask a new question with a fully reproducible example (I had to define things like `num_photon` and `energy_sigma` myself to test your example) with some expected output.